# How can I make sure my deployed app is not running in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

How can I make sure my deployed app is not running in development mode?

I'm using capistrano for the first time so just a bit wary

I'm using ubuntu, nginx and passenger (ree).

Comment: If you want to ensure a particular environment, say `production` or `staging`, then you can edit your server's `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to set the environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Passenger then try

```
RailsEnv production
```

in your site's configuration.  Your capistrano `deploy.rb` should add a `RAILS_ENV=production` to things like `rake` commands (this is done by default).

(By default RailsEnv production should be used, but yours may say "RailsEnv development".)

By the above I mean in your `vhosts.conf` or wherever your distro's Apache stores its site configurations.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName blah.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/yourrailsapp/public
   RailsEnv production

   <Directory /var/www/yourrailsapp/public>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: where is this done by default?  I don't see any reference to RAILS_ENV in my deploy.rb file?

Comment: If you have seed data you might see a `task :seed do` that uses `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production`; what web server are you using to host your app?  If for some reason you're using WEBrick you can do `rails s RAILS_ENV=production` (in Rails 3) though I would not recommend this.

Comment: you want to go in your Apache configuration files to do this, you don't have to do it every time (via capistrano), just once to the virtual host file for your app. Restart apache and you're set.

Comment: I'm using nginx, should have mentioned that also.

Comment: I know literally nothing about nginx other than its a web server.  I would hope that it runs production by default but that doesn't sound like your experience.  I guess try: http://www.modrails.com/videos/passenger_nginx.mov

Comment: Watching that it looks like rails_env production will be default using Passenger with nginx but you could specify it as production just to be sure.

Comment: I wish my app would work (its giving an error) so I can output the rails envir and see what it says!

Comment: if you can ssh into the server, can't you also rails c RAILS_ENV=production?

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to one of your pages:

```
<%= Rails.env %>
```

It will say "production" or "development"

Comment: I did rails console on the server, and it says development.  I guess I have to tell capistrano to change to production somehow?

Comment: Are you using Passenger with Apache or something else?

Comment: @Blankman: Console will default to production unless an environment has been specified. Either as an argument to the command, or as an environment variable.

Comment: I don't think that right. Console defaults to development, to get it to run in another mode you just tack RAILS_ENV=production (or whatever) at the end of your command. Passenger runs in production by default http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application

Comment: I think concept47 is correct, that's been my experience on deploying my current Rails 3 project.